# Trouble presenting view controller from within VC within UITabViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

My app is built around a UITabBarController and within the first View Controller I am attempting to present a "settings view" for a user but for some reason if this settings view gets presented more than once all buttons stop functioning and the app shits down completely.

Within FirstViewController.m I have:

```
- (IBAction)showSettings:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *settingsView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingsViewController"];

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsView];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];  
}
```

which is attached to a UIButton labeled "settings".

Within SettingsViewController.m I have:

```
- (IBAction)done
{
    NSLog(@"DONE");

    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];   
 }
```

which is attached to a UIButton labeled "done" in the top left corner of SettingsViewController.

The first time I press "settings" then "done" it works without a problem but if I ever press the "settings" button again the "done" button loses functionality completely (completely unclickable) and the user is forced to restart the app in order to continue using it.

My console prints this when the app loads which I believe outlines the problem:

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for 
<UITabBarController: 0x7f97f5f1e780>
```

But if I try to make an instance of "TabBarController" and present the view that way I just get an error that I am attempting to present a VC not within the hierarchy...

I am just not sure what the appropriate way to present/dismiss a view controller within a UITabBarController is but as of right not my app is lacking basic functionality. I don't see why FirstViewController can't just present the view normally.

Any help is greatly appreciated, this is a very annoying Bug and I wasn't able to find a workable solution anywhere else online. Let me know if I should provide more info/code

Edit: Changed typo UITabViewController to UITabBarController

Comment: Minor point: There is no such thing as a UITabViewController.

Comment: It's odd that you say `self.navigationController`. You have not explained where this navigation controller is, in your view controller hierarchy.

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to present and dismiss a `UINavigationController` in concert with your `SettingsViewController` ?

Comment: try [self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];  and [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: @matt Sorry that was a typo I meant TabBarController. self.navigation is the syntax I am used to using/seeing and it has always worked for me. I have tried just 'self' it changes nothing. Passing just SettingsViewController and not the UINavigationController results in the exception: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller'

Comment: @ColeXia I've tried this it doesnt change anything and the issue Im having is still there.

Comment: Okay, so you didn't answer the question I asked, can't help.

Comment: @matt I'm not sure honestly, like I said self.navigation controller is the syntax im used to seeing. Ive always understood that self.navigationController is just the navigation controller of the VC and its what you use to push views. I never define it myself. But like I said, If I remove the ".navigationController" everything acts the exact same so I don't believe that where it is in my hierarchy is particularly important in solving the problem (maybe it is, idk what im doing). I apologize if I am being difficult, I clearly dont understand much of how this all works.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why you are instantiating a Nav controller.
Simply show modally. it should work.
Do you need a "go back" look and feel?

If you already have a nav controller in your hierarchy you can push settings.

**anyway:** when you do:

```
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settingsView];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:nil];
```

in first line you create a LOCAL variable
in second you use self. self.navigationController

1) who holds "nav"?

2) If you already have a nav controller (as self.navigationController shows.. or is NIL?) why use "nav"?

Comment: Sorry if this is rude but your response honestly is not an answer to my question. It is a comment. Self.navigation is not nil. I have already stated this in another comment but if I don't use *nav and call `[self presentViewController:settingsView animated:YES completion:nil];` I get the error 'Application tried to present modally an active controller.' If you have an idea about how I could change my code in anyway I am all ears. Do answer your first question, Yes I need a "go back" look and feel. What do you mean "simply show modally"? Isnt that what I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you set the dismiss to the navigation controller and not the settings view controller. Try using self.dismiss instead of self.navigationcontroller.dismiss

Comment: I have tried this and tried it again when I saw your answer. It does not change functionality and the issue I describe persists.

Answer (score 0):

You to define root view controller for navigation push and pop both

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navController;

self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: objcReg];
self.navController.navigationBarHidden =YES;

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] ;
self.window.rootViewController = self.navController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

//[self.navigationController presentViewController:objectofViewCantroller animated:YES completion:NULL];
//[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Getting the error `Application tried to present modally an active controller` but I'm confused about a couple things. First of all am I correct to be putting all but the first and last two lines of code in viewDidLoad for FirstViewController? Also what is objcReg? Is it supposed to be FirstViewController? Also confused why the last two lines are commented out. Thanks!

Comment: last 2 lines is commented which ever you want to pop or push you can uncomment that line and use it . objcReg is controller object from which you want to push or pop sorry for not explaining hat in my answer